# Difference between setting an NSMutableURLRequest header and adding one

Tags: ios, swift, http-headers, nsmutableurlrequest

I was wondering what the difference between setting a header value and adding a header value to an NSMutableURLRequest is. Sounds sort of obvious but, for example, can't you just use addValue every time? Will setting a header that doesn't exist throw an error? Will adding a header when it already exists in the request overwrite the existing value?

example

```
let request.NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "someURL")!) 
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
...
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the discussion in Apple's official doc is quite clear:

**[addValue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1407676-addvalue)**

> This method provides the ability to add values to header fields incrementally. If a value was previously set for the specified field, the supplied value is **appended** to the existing value using the appropriate field delimiter. In the case of HTTP, the **delimiter** is a *comma*.

**[setValue](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1408793-setvalue)**

> The *new* value for the header field. Any existing value for the field
>   is **replaced** by the new value.

---

`setValue` replaces. `addValue` appends with a delimiter

Comment: Oh wow ok this has clarified my understanding hugely! unless appending values to current headers I should use set value? In my mind 'addValue' seemed like another term for 'add a header'..

Comment: @Danoram Depends on what you are trying to accomplish. I feel that setValue is enough for most circumstances.

Comment: What if  we "setValue" for non existing key? Will crash with unknown key exception I guess!

Comment: No, App won't crash if we put setValue which has not exist but there will no impact to request and response at all. I think setValue should use always. Because when we use header field means already they are defined inside database.